# How to connect two VMs with each other in Azure

Tags: azure, connection, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012-r2

I prepared two virtual machines with Windows Server 2012. I want allow them to communicate with each other: I opened port and disabled firewall on both machines, but when I try to ping one VM from another one using private or public IP address and when I am using telnet, I have problem with timeout. Both are in same virtual network. What else should I do?

Comment: any network security group is set from the virtual machine--networking? Could you RDP each other?

Comment: if they are inside the same vnet by default they would be able to talk to each other unless you explicitly blocked traffic on nsg. if you haven't done so - check your setup inside vms. firewall, apps listening on ports etc

Comment: I can connect with RDP to both servers, but when I use on VM1 telnet and try to connect VM2, I have connection timeout. Same problem when I do the same on VM2. I opened all connections, but still l have this problem.

Comment: Could you telnet VM2 with port 3389 on Vm1 with its private IP or public IP?

Comment: Yes, telnet works fine with port 3389

Comment: If you have NSG, could you show the configuration as my reply display? Use the command `netstat -anbo` on VMs to check if the port you want to telnet is listening. Show me the output of ping or telnet. Ps, Feel free to leave a message under my reply then I will get a note message sent from you.

Comment: "PS C:\Users\qwertynski> telnet 13.84.149.245 1443
Connecting To 13.84.149.245...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1443: Connect failed"
If I use 3389 which is used for RDP connection, telnet works fine. I setup network connections with the same options marked as for RDP connection, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Do you have service is listening on port 1433 on Azure VM? If not, telnet will not work with the port. Maybe you should update your question to make it specific and clear. I can not find your message in time, could you follow up in "add a comment" below the Answer?

Comment: Any update on your side?

Answer (score 0):

By default, VMs in the same VNet could communicate with each other with any port and any protocol in the NSG unless you have added some inbound or outbound port rules with high priority. Also some rules in windows firewall blocks on the VMs.

[image]

In this case, you could check if the app or service is started and the port is listening for `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: If you have some question, please let me know.